# Error when trying to output "Fizz" while trying to run FizzBuzz

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple FizzBuzz program that's easily editable to work with different numbers as well as more numbers if I need it to.

When I run the program, the numbers are printed fine and "Buzz" gets printed fine. However, when I print "Fizz" it prints `Fizz` and then on the next number it also prints `Fizz` along with the number.

For example:

`1, 2, Fizz, Fizz4, Buzz.`

```
public void Buzz(int limit){
    for(int i = 1; i<limit; i++){
        if(i%3 == 0){
            output += "Fizz";
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        if(i%5 == 0){
            output += "Buzz";
            System.out.println(output);
        }else{
            output += i;
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        output = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `+=` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently checks if `i % 3 == 0`, and then checks if `i % 5 == 0`. If the second if statement fails then the number is printed out in addition to `Fizz` if it was printed out before.

You might consider this something like this code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/11489) if you would prefer not to use `%15`, which would have your code looking something like:

```
public void Buzz(int limit){
    for(int i = 1; i<limit; i++){

        boolean fizzOrBuzz = false;

        if(i % 3 == 0){
            fizzOrBuzz = true;
            System.out.print("Fizz");
        }

        if(i % 5 == 0){
            fizzOrBuzz = true;
            System.out.print("Buzz");
        }

        if (fizzOrBuzz) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/11491) gives a version which uses `%15` which you may find nicer.

Edit: Update `println` to `print` according to @Nexevis's comment.